# Entity framework - How to flatten nested objects with all the foreign key

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, flatten

I need to flatten the result of entityframework query including nested objects, Let me explain with an example

**User Table** 
[image]

**Role Table** 
[image]

**User Role Junction Table** 
[image]

**Expected Result using Entityframework** 
[image]

Comment: Use `Select()` such as `context.UserRoles.Select(x => new { x.User.UserId, x.Role.RoleId, x.User.Name, x.Role.Role}).ToList();`  The key is to ensure that EF is configured to know how your models relate to one another.  From there you can leverage `Select()` to reduce your expression and build an efficient query for just the data you need.

Comment: Thanks your answer is correct for my question, but i didn't mean that, Let me edit the question in a while.